# Why won't this code allow me to place a checkmark accessory in my tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

When I look to run this on my phone, no checkmark is assigned to the cell after I segue back and forth from my detailViewController. They currently have  no checkmark assigned, so I am looking to assign a checkmark to the cell once it has been selected. PLease let me know if you know what is going on here! Thanks

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
     if cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are dequeuing a new cell, not necessarily the one being selected. However,you should persist whether or not the cell is checked using a model object, not persist state within the view itself. Once the cell is dequeued/reused, it'll no longer be selected.

For example, you'd have an array of model objects:

```
class YourObject {
   var isSelected: Bool = false
}

var modelObjects: [YourObject] = []
```

Inside each object there would be a property representing whether or not the object is selected, this would be set inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
var object = self.modelObjects[indexPath.row]
object.isSelected = true
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], rowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can check if the property on the model object is selected, if so, set the cell's accessoryType to .Checkmark.

```
var object = self.modelObjects[indexPath.row]

if object.isSelected {
   cell.accessoryType  .Checkmark
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` dequeues a cell that is not being currently displayed by the `tableView`, it does not return the cell that it's being displayed at that index path.

What you want to use is `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, which will give you the cell for that index path if it's being displayed by the `tableView`.

If you set the `accessoryType` to that cell, it will update the visible cell.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing, you are dequeuing a new cell instead of updating the cell that is being selected. In order to achieve what you want you shoul replace this `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)` with `let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)`.

Answer (score 0):

We must handler the 'if' and 'else' both.

In 'cellForRowAtIndexPath':

```
private var selectedIndex: Int = -1    

if selectedIndex == indexPath.row
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
}
```